# JHipster Registry rejects gateways and microservices

Tags: jwt, jhipster, microservices, spring-cloud-config

I'm trying to use JHipster for a project using microservices, but the latest JHipster Registry won't let my gateway or microservices access the config server and rejects them.

I installed the JHipster Vagrant DevBox, then used `docker run -p 8761:8761 jhipster/jhipster-registry` to run the JHipster registry.
Then, I generated a gateway and 2 microservices following [this](http://www.ipponusa.com/blog/jhipster-3-0-introducing-microservices/), and it worked.

But then I wanted to use the JHipster Registry from GitHub, so I cloned it and runned it (apparently it had been updated to 2.0.0 in the meantime). Sadly, the gateway and the microservices weren't able to access this registry. They were still able to access the Docker image registry though (I suppose Docker didn't update it). But since it was fancier, and probably more up-to-date, I wanted to use the latest version of the registry, the same as the one from GitHub. So I tried to update the Docker image Jhipster Registry with `docker pull`. And now it won't work with either registry - Docker image or GitHub clone.

When a registry is running and I run a gateway or microservice, I get 6 times this:

```
2016-05-10 15:39:07.511 DEBUG 20706 --- [           main] s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection  : sun.net.www.MessageHeader@86ba8f5 pairs: {GET /config/gateway/dev/master HTTP/1.1: null}{Accept: application/json, application/*+json}{User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_91}{Host: localhost:8761}{Connection: keep-alive}
2016-05-10 15:39:07.522 DEBUG 20706 --- [           main] s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection  : sun.net.www.MessageHeader@43c7802510 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized}{Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1}{X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff}{X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block}{Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate}{Pragma: no-cache}{Expires: 0}{Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8}{Transfer-Encoding: chunked}{Date: Tue, 10 May 2016 15:39:07 GMT}
```

Then I get an error:

```
2016-05-10 15:39:13.781 ERROR 20706 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
```

Then I get Java exceptions:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not locate PropertySource and the fail fast property is set, failing
at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.locate(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:110)
at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fa44b2a.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor$1.doWithRetry(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:74)
at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:263)
at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:154)
at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:101)
at org.springframework.retry.annotation.AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a0abff82.locate(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java:89)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:640)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:343)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
at com.soprasteria.example.GatewayApp.main(GatewayApp.java:73)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:478)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:641)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:597)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:475)
at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.getRemoteEnvironment(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:130)
at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.locate(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:81)
... 23 common frames omitted

[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:478)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not locate PropertySource and the fail fast property is set, failing
at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.locate(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:110)
at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fa44b2a.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor$1.doWithRetry(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:74)
at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:263)
at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:154)
at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:101)
at org.springframework.retry.annotation.AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a0abff82.locate(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java:89)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:640)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:343)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
at com.soprasteria.example.GatewayApp.main(GatewayApp.java:73)
... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:641)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:597)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:475)
at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.getRemoteEnvironment(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:130)
at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.locate(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:81)
... 23 more
```

And finally a `BUILD FAILURE` and a Maven error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project gateway: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Could not locate PropertySource and the fail fast property is set, failing: 401 Unauthorized -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

In the registry's shell I get this line 6 times too:

```
2016-05-10 15:39:07.519 DEBUG 17958 --- [io-8761-exec-10] i.g.j.r.s.Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint  : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
```

I tried updating everything, and I am currently trying to downgrade things (since the doc says "we recommend you use the same version tag as the one you use for your JHipster generator", but I don't think it'll work since JHipster Registry's latest version is 2.0.0 and the JHipster generator introduced microservices with the 3.0 version), and I also tried copying directly the secret from the central-server-config to the config of the applications, but apparently to no avail.

Could you help me with this ?

Thank you very much in advance.

EDIT:

I tried updating JHipster to 3.2.1 using `npm install -g generator-jhipster`, which apparently worked, but when I run `yo jhipster`, Yeoman still uses JHipster 3.1.0. Actually, even if I uninstall JHipster with `npm uninstall -g generator-jhipster`, Yeoman can still use JHipster 3.1.0...

EDIT:

It works fine if I reinstall everything locally (in the directory where I use `yo jhipster`).
However, I still can't update JHipster globally in Yeoman. When I try using `npm install -g generator-jhipster`, it updates JHipster globally to 3.2.1 but Yeoman still uses 3.1.0. If I try to update JHipster using `yo`/"Update your generators"/generator-jhipster, I get an error:

```
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
/usr/local/lib
└── generator-jhipster@3.2.1 

npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-85-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "generator-jhipster"
npm ERR! node v4.4.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.9
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/npm-debug.log

I've just updated your generators. Remember, you can update
a specific generator with npm by running:

    npm install -g generator-_______
```

Using `sudo` will do the same and `sudo su` give me this when I try to run `yo`:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/configstore/index.js:53
                throw err;
                ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/root/.config/configstore/insight-yo.json'
You don't have access to this file.

    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:549:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:397:15)
    at Object.create.all.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/configstore/index.js:34:26)
    at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/configstore/index.js:27:44)
    at new Insight (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/lib/index.js:37:34)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js:163:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
```

EDIT:

Ok it does **not** work even with a local installation...
Well the gateway does access to the registry, but it displays a debug page when I try to access to localhost:8080.
Actually, during the generation, I get a `permission denied` again, and missing dependencies (`gulp-rev`).

I just saw this: "It is wise to use a tag to have a stable version: the JHipster DevBox tags are the same as the JHipster Generator tags, so using the DevBox v3.2.0 also means using the generator v3.2.0" on the DevBox GitHub page, so maybe I'll just delete and download the DevBox again...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you upgraded the JHipster Registry to the 2.0.0 version. This new version is secured, and that's why you have 401 "unauthenticated" errors, as you didn't provide any login/password to connect.

3 solutions:

- Stay with the older JHipster Registry version, that matches your JHipster version.
- Add a login/password (by default it's admin/admin) to your Eureka and Spring Cloud Config URLs. The detailed documentation on securing the JHipster Registry is [here](http://jhipster.github.io/microservices-architecture/) - it is incomplete at the time of this writing, but I will update it shortly
- Update to JHipster v3.2.1, that is meant to be used with JHipster Registry v2.0.0, and where everything will be automatically configured.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer.

Comment: I was thinking about your first solution while writing my question, it should work since it worked before.
I don't know exactly how to use your second solution, but I will try it.
For you third solution, I thought I had updated JHipster to its latest version already, but I just noticed that, if I use `npm install -g generator-jhipster`, it indeed install the 3.2.1 version, but yeoman still use the 3.1.0 version when I run `yo jhipster`, so I don't know exactly how to update it.

Comment: Somehow just typing `yo` to enter the cli based menu and update through it works while the command line `npm install -g generator-jhipster` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same behavior when using the latest JHipster Registry pulled from github running locally with IntelliJ IDEA -- the server would start but the frontend would not serve up.

It turned out to be an issue with a blank working directory in the Run/Debug Configuration.  Once that is populated, things work find from the IDE.